# Using AppKit With SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, macos, menu, sprite-kit, appkit

Since I've learned Objective C I've only used the SpriteKit project template. I've had a tiny bit of exposure to iOS development and I'm looking to use AppKit elements (buttons, etc) in an OS X SpriteKit project for menu creation, overlays or having more flexibility in terms of placing items on the screen. Is this possible and if so, how? Would it be something along the lines of layering views (NSView overtop of an SKView) or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the same as iOS. You can use NSWindowController and NSViewController to hold an SKView and place elements above the view.

In my case I actually just ended up using Sprite Kit for all of the UI because I didn't want to have to mange two separate interfaces.

I recommend that you don't use the Sprite Kit template but instead use the default Cocoa App Template because it uses newer interface technologies that will make designing your interface easier and more similar to iOS.

Comment: @02fentym if you stick with Sprite Kit for your UI you have the advantage to use it both in OSX and iOS if you decide to do so in the future.

Comment: That's a good point Skyler, although I don't think I'd ever port it to iOS. Creating UI elements from scratch by subclassing SKSpriteNode in SpriteKit is such a pain!

@Epic Byte: I've never done anything like that for iOS. As I said up top, I've had very little exposure to iOS and I've played with storyboarding a bit. When you say `place elements above the view` are you talking about laying things out through storyboard?I'm lost.

Comment: @02fentym If I were you I would look up some iOS interface tutorials and learn how storyboard, auto layout, view controllers, views etc work. Then learn the OS X interface stuff as it will be a smooth transition. Alternatively you can look up some tutorials on OS X interface development however many tutorials are outdated and don't take advantage of the new interface technologies such as NSViewController. You can also try creating a default Cocoa App template and just mess around in the storyboard to learn how it works too. I'm not you so I don't know the extent of your experience.

Comment: Yeah, I completely agree with you. The hardest thing with learning Objective C is that so many things have changed in just the last couple of years that when I look at tutorials and other forums, it's hard to get a handle on what is outdated and what is current. The hardest thing was memory management...I still feel like I'm not doing everything correctly. I look at Apple's sample code, but I find their way of thinking is so advanced that I'm light years away from designing my projects with the paradigms they employ. Do you have any tutorials that you can point me to that would be helpful?